# Moving adhoc distributed app to iTunes - Lite vs Paid App

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, ad-hoc-distribution, itunes-store, udid

I have an app which i used to distribute to users adhocly by adding UDID to provisioning profile. I want to move that app to iTunes now, keeping free and paid versions of the app. How can I give full version of the app for free to my current clients? Is it possible without server involvement ?

Answer (score 0):

How many users do you have? If not more than 100 then you can use [promo codes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ProvidingPromoCodes.html)

Comment: of course they can't. you'll be allowed to create new pack of promo codes just when you release new version of your app.